# capture the user visited categories information in my website

Tags: java, web

I have an entertainment website. When a first-time user visits my site, I need to capture which categories he has visited. Like, if the user visits the images related to flowers then I need to capture the "flowers" keyword and the IP address of the user's machine, then store it in my database. If in the future, the same user logs into my site, then I need to display the last visited categories first.

How can I do this? I have created a table with the field's IP address, date, and time. I used the following program for getting the IP address:

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class IpFinder {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    InetAddress ip;
    try {
      ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
      System.out.println("Current IP address : " + ip.getHostAddress());
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this  will return the ip address of my own machine. but i want to get ip address of visitors of my website

Comment: You can't count on IP addresses being unique, or not changing between visits. You could use cookies to tell if you've seen a user before.

Comment: i need to do this one using java. i have to prepare one algorithm that contains visitors visted information in my site. i dont understand from where i need to start. please guide me to do this one

Answer (score 3):

You cannot reliably get the IP address of a visitor, this is hidden behind firewalls, proxies, etc. etc. and are not available.

For these kind of things we normally use Cookies. A simple google search will return plenty of tutorials on how to use cookies to get you started.

Comment: you can reliably get the IP addr of the visitor. but if 18 of us are in a dorm building at the Univ of Texas and going to the OP's website, we will all appear as the same IP addr. Then I am like, hey, I didn't look at pink lingerie last time I was there ... because in fact it was Raza. Otherwise you are correct about cookies.

Comment: LOL, yes that's exactly what I meant by "Reliably". It can get confused :) (and +1)

Comment: am new to to java programming. please guide me how to proceed

Comment: @user2388481: the answer to this question is what Raza and I told you, "Don't do that." (If you really need to get ipaddresses you can get those from the HttpRequest, but they aren't helpful for what you describe.) Keep in mind this site is for answering specific technical questions, it works better when you create focused questions, as opposed to wide-open pleas for help.